# Creating an ordered list of Objects but when comparing two Objects if they are numbers it does not come out correctly?

Tags: java, object, comparison, compareto

I am implementing a "modified sequential search" method we learned in class. The user inputs the item they want to add and it is sent to my modSeqSearch method. In the method the first item is compared to user's item -- it first checks if the user's item is greater than the current item, then checks if they are equal, and then there is an else for it being less than. Two Objects are being compared and I am using compareTo and toString for both Objects. If my list is {1 2 3 4 5} and I add a 10, it goes between the 1 and 2, opposed to the end. I can't seem to get around this problem. Any ideas?

```
    private static int modSeqSearch(ListArrayBasedPlus lABPlus, Object item)
    {
        int i = 0;
        boolean checking = true;
        int length = lABPlus.size();
        int position = 0;
        while(checking)
        {
            if (item.toString().compareTo(lABPlus.get(i).toString()) > 0) //key is greater than current key
            {
                position = i++;
                if (i == length)
                {
                    position = -i;
                    checking = false;
                }
            }
            else if (item.equals(lABPlus.get(i))) //key is equal to current key
            {
                position = i;
                checking = false;
            }
            else //key does not exist
            {
                position = -i;
                checking = false;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: You're only executing your loop once. It checks to see if 10 is greater then 1, increments position, then sets sentinel value to false which exits the loop.

Comment: I don't think that's it because if I add 20 to the list it goes between 2 and 3, 30 goes between 3 and 4, and 40 goes between 4 and 5. I know it's doing it by lexicographic order, but I need to figure out how to not do it by that way.

Comment: Do something like `Integer.valueOf(String str)`. That's only if you are sure it will be a number. There is a `valueOf` method for Doubles, Integers, Longs, etc.

Comment: I thought about trying that but unfortunately the two values being entered can be anything.